# Lightning Communities 'Edit Meta Tags' not working for IE 11

Tags: lightning, community

In Lightning Communities does the new page level feature to 'Edit Meta Tags' work for IE 11? When we add simple meta tags we get the following error, but all other browsers worked:

Action failed: forceCommunity:seoAssistant$controller$init [Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'] Callback failed: serviceComponent://ui.comm.runtime.components.aura.components.siteforce.controller.PubliclyCacheableComponentLoaderController/ACTION$getPageComponent

Comment: Note: <3% of the Internet is now using IE 11 or lower. It's time to stop testing in IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE 11 [is not supported](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&type=5) in lightning experience. I would not expect any new features, or even the features which are currently supported, to work with this browser. The [official recommendation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Internet-Explorer-Performance-Characteristics-for-Lightning-Experience&type=1) is to use another browser, or have users use classic when in IE 11.

> Support for Internet Explorer 11 to access Lightning Experience is retiring beginning in Summer ’16.

---

From a technical perspective, its due to the `forEach` function for some list being missing - it's [likely not supported by the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

If you have control over the scripts loaded on this page, and assuming its a `NodeList` which is missing the `forEach`, you can try to add this poly-fill to the page, in order to prevent this error from occurring:

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = function (callback, thisArg) {
        thisArg = thisArg || window;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
        }
    };
}
```

You might need a different target object, but the idea is the same.

Comment: We were able to get it working with that code snippet. Thanks!